# notepad++ - how to get a session back when upgrading windows

Tags: notepad++

I recently have upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 10, so when my Windows finished I lost my Notepad++ session but not my files.

Do you know how to get the session back or the unsaved and/or opened files?

notepad++ have the option to work without saving files, but i dont know where does it save these.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you save the session? What does *files opened or without save* mean? If you never saved the files, and the system rebooted during the upgrade, they're lost. (Although why someone would upgrade their OS with unsaved files in an editor is baffling; clearly an OS upgrade will require a restart, and clearly unsaved files will not survive that restart.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the case without an operating system upgrade:

- there is a file session.xml in which notepad++ stores its opened files. It even **stores unsaved files** here (I guess you have to configure the *Backup* feature in the preferences before)
- see [notepad-plus-plus.org](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Configuration_Files) for more information, especially section *"3 Where are the files ?"*
- also take care of the hint given after doLocalConf.xml about the *"two sets"* of configuration files

In my installation the file is in notepad++.exe's directory and the unsaved files are stored in the backup folder configured in the preferences. You find out the paths by looking inside the session.xml.

Comment: Excelent i just get it on C:\Windows.old\Users\oscard\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup I found them all and got it back. when the system got upgrade it save all files on Windows.old directory. thanks for your help