# Python: .py file emptied

Tags: python-2.7, notepad++

I run a .py file a few times a day, and I make only time changes to it.
It just completely emptied out. It is a blank file now, and I lost my code.
This happened as I was saving this file in Notepad++ with an updated time. 
Is there any way to recuperate this?

Comment: do you have a file size 0 KB with a time stamp matching your saving time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, 0 KB and time stamp of saving time.

Comment: Try to use one of those file recovery 'undelete' softwares. One of my favourite is [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva)

Comment: If you have notepad++ backup feature configured, you might try my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699772/notepad-how-to-get-a-session-back-when-upgrading-windows/33708493?s=6%7C8.7741#33708493

Comment: @ Lars Fischer: thank you, that did the trick !